# Shell script options with parsing arguments

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have the shell script

```
CONTROLLER_IP=""
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]
then
    CONTROLLER_IP=$1
else
    echo "Usage : create_endpoint.sh --controller-ip <Controller IP>"
    exit 1
fi
```

but its executing like this .`/create_endpoint.sh 10.10.10.1`

I want to execute like this `/create_endpoint.sh --controller-ip 10.10.10.1`

Comment: So are you trying to set it so that it accepts an option of --controller-ip rather than just typing the IP as the first argument?

Comment: yes. I need like that

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTROLLER_IP=""

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
  case $1 in
    -c|--controller-ip)
      if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        CONTROLLER_IP="$2"
        shift 2
        continue
      else
        echo "ERROR: '--controller-ip' requires a non-empty option argument."
        exit 1
      fi
        ;;
    -h|-\?|--help)
      echo "Usage: $(basename $0) --controller-ip <ip>"
      exit
      ;;
    --)              # End of all options.
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      echo "WARN: Unknown option (ignored): $1"
      ;;
    *)               # Default case: If no more options then break out of the loop.
      break
  esac
  shift
done

echo "$CONTROLLER_IP"
```

---

*Examples*

```
$ ./foo --controller-ip 192.168.2.1
192.168.2.1

$ ./foo -c 192.168.2.1
192.168.2.1

$ ./foo --controller-ip
ERROR: '--controller-ip' requires a non-empty option argument.

$ ./foo --help
Usage: foo --controller-ip <ip>

$ ./foo -help
WARN: Unknown option (ignored): -help
```

---

As OP commented:

> I don't want help option.

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTROLLER_IP=""

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
  case $1 in
    -c|--controller-ip)
      if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        CONTROLLER_IP=$2
        shift 2
        continue
      else
        echo "ERROR: '--controller-ip' requires a non-empty option argument."
        exit 1
      fi
        ;;
    --)              # End of all options.
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      echo "WARN: Unknown option (ignored): $1"
      ;;
    *)               # Default case: If no more options then break out of the loop.
      break
  esac
    shift
done

echo "$CONTROLLER_IP"
```

Comment: I don't want help option.

Comment: @Ubuntu-Beginner Take the 2nd version.

Comment: if i have multiple arguments. how can I do that

Comment: @Ubuntu-Beginner In the same way as for `-c|--controller-ip)`

Comment: @Ubuntu-Beginner Don't thank me! ;-) If my answer is correct, just click the little grey **☑** under the "2" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 2, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to [askubuntu.com/questions/ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: CONTROLLER_IP=""
neutron_ip=""
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
  case $1 in
    -c|--controller-ip)
      if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        CONTROLLER_IP=$2
        shift 2
        continue
      else
        echo "ERROR: '--controller-ip' requires a non-empty option argument."
        exit 1
      fi
        ;;
      --neutron-ip)
        if [ -n "$2" ]
        neutron_ip=$2
        shift 2
        continue
        else
         echo "Error '--neutron-ip'"
        exit 1
        fi
    --)              # End of all options.

Comment: shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      echo "WARN: Unknown option (ignored)"
        exit 1
      ;;
    *)               # Default case: If no more options then break out of the loop.
      break
  esac
    shift
done

echo "$CONTROLLER_IP"
echo $neutron_ip

Comment: not working. please check and tell

Answer (score 4):

The `getopt` command is used for parsing options in bash scripts there's a great guide to its use [here](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt).

You can set long or short options, and also specify whether the option has required or optional arguments with use of `:` or `::`.

Don't confuse it with the bash builtin `getopts` which can only read short options, and processes slightly differently.

I found this [guide](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html) to the differences between the two simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to use a code generator such as [Argbash](https://argbash.io), that will generate the argument handling code for you. There are also universal [bash libraries for argument parsing](http://argbash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/others.html), but you would have to distribute them with your script, and they are quite long and complex.

Why?

- The answer suggesting using `getopt` is not a good choice - its support of long options is a GNU extension, so scripts using it are not portable. Plus `getopt` has its own issues besides that.
- The answer suggesting writing `bash` argument parsing code also has an issue - maintaining relatively long hand-written code like this doesn't feel right.

Finally, arguments that begin with dashes are commonly known as *optional* and treated as such - they should not be required and if they are omitted, a sensible default should be available. Therefore, the original script you are somehow unhappy about, may actually be the best solution.