# How can I add options to a custom made command?

Tags: command-line

I want to add options to a custom command. I create my commands by putting a .sh document in /bin. Is it possible to add a "-x" option to my code? (i.e. customcommand -c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script options with parsing arguments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643931/shell-script-options-with-parsing-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample file: multi_arg.sh

```
echo $1 #Echo out the first argument

echo $2 #Echo out the second argument

echo $3 #Echo out the 3 argument
```

Test Run:

$ sh multi_arg.sh a b c

```
a
b
c
```

Another test run (with -c e.g)

$ sh ABC.sh -a -b -c

```
-a
-b
-c
```

Related:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias

Comment: This is 1 way (although I do not know if it is what you're exactly after, if not please write that :))

Comment: Oh you're right, My bad;  accidentally  copied 1 line from another file when I wrote the current, Thanks for pointing it out.